# How programmatically remove default import in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

By default some packages are imported in a Groovy class. I know that you can add new one with an ImportCustomizer but is there a way to remove them programmatically?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I don't believe there is...

Comment: i think some instrumentation might work.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you look through the code, then you'll see that the [standard imports](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Java) like `java.io` and `java.math.BigDecimal` are not handled by `ImportCustomizer`.

Which is a pity.

The default imports are handled in [ResolveVisitor.java](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/control/ResolveVisitor.java#L54). The code doesn't allow to modify the default imports or the method where they are added.

Kudos to [andrei-krotkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54648/andrei-krotkov) for finding the code.

Comment: It looks like they're defined at https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/control/ResolveVisitor.java#L54 but I see no way of removing it. :(

Answer (score 1):

It is not a pretty good solution but it works:

```
Arrays.fill(ResolveVisitor.DEFAULT_IMPORTS, "java.lang.");
```